# How to find out unresolved symbols in aix?

Tags: ld, aix, xlc

In linux, gcc reports unresolved symbols if there is any. How should I use ld to generate such information in aix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ld on AIX reports unresolved symbols by default.

Are you using the -brtl option when linking? In that case, you are requesting that the linking occurs at runtime (runtime linking), and therefore ld will not report any unresolved symbols as it is assumed any unresolved symbols will be provided in libraries used when the program is run. (Any unresolved symbols will be reported when one attempts to run the program.)